# SQL Aggregate in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

What I have to do is:

```
2. Write a SELECT statement that answers this question: 
    Which products have a list price that’s greater than the average list price for all products?
        Return the ProductName and ListPrice columns for each product.
        Sort the results by the ListPrice column in descending sequence.
```

SQL code that I have come up with:

```
SELECT ProductName, ListPrice
FROM Products
WHERE Products.ListPrice > AVG(ListPrice) 
ORDER BY ListPrice DESC
```

However this gives me error:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

However when I calculated the AVG manually and plug it in as a raw int as:

```
SELECT ProductName, ListPrice
FROM Products
WHERE Products.ListPrice > 841.895 
ORDER BY ListPrice DESC
```

This works. Why is this? How come AVG(ListPrice) <> 841.895??

What is the best way to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

The aggregate function `AVG()` will give the average value over a group. If you use an aggregate without a `GROUP BY`, there isn't a defined group. That is why your first query failed. You can get around that limitation by using a subquery:

```
SELECT ProductName, ListPrice
  FROM Products
 WHERE ListPrice > ( SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Products )
 ORDER BY ListPrice DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing a calculated field that isn't returned in the query itself.

WHERE clauses can only reference data that exists somewhere, but, luckily for you, it can exist in a subquery, nested within your WHERE clause.

The other option would be to try to put that in a HAVING clause, instead of WHERE.  However, in this case you would be best served by putting your AVG inside a subquery, something like.

```
SELECT ProductName, ListPrice
FROM Products
WHERE Products.ListPrice > (SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Products)
```

This statement will create a temporary subtable that is referenced by your "WHERE" clause.

Answer (score -1):

The above questions are all funny ways to do it. The best way to do it is using the "HAVING" clause which comes AFTER the where clause.

You would write it like this:

```
SELECT ProductName, ListPrice
FROM Products
group by productName,ListPrice
having Products.ListPrice > AVG(ListPrice) ;
```

You can think of HAVING as a WHERE clause that deals with aggregate columns.

Comment: @WalkerFarrow, the reason your query won't work is that the value of `AVG(ListPrice)` when grouped by `ListPrice` will just be `ListPrice` (the average of one value)! So your query won't return anything at all since `ListPrice` will never be greater than itself.

Comment: Yes, I realized that.... I was just trying to explain what a HAVING clause is - which he didn't seem to undrestand.... But yeah, thats what occurs.